# Search in other table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `maintenance` table with the following fields: `id`, `car_id`, `type`, and `name`.

How do I get list of entries from `maintenance` table where `type = 'car wash'` but only with `model_id = 5`?

`model_id` field are in the `car` table. Car table with the following fields: `id`, `model_id`, `engine_size`, and `color`.

How can I use `Maintenance::where` to get list of entries with matching `model_id` in a `car` table? There is `car_id` in a `maintenance` table which link with `car` table.

Do I need to do something like this: ?

```
  return Maintenance::where('type', 'car_wash')->where(function($query) {
       // get a list a maintenance where model_id = 5 in a car table
  });
```

Comment: It is not duplicate, read the question again.

Comment: @chris85 In the `maintenance` table, it has `car_id` and in the `car`table  it has `id` and `model_id` fields.

Comment: I didn't realise I have to use `->join` because the relationship already setup between Maintenance.php and Car.php (model php files)

Comment: I'll leave this to someone that's worked with laravel more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already defined cars() relation on your Maintenance model you could try something like that:

```
$model_id = 5;
$type = 'car_wash';
return Maintenance::whereHas('cars',function($query) use($model_id,$type) {
  $query->where('model_id',$model_id)->where('type',$type);
  })->get();
```

Update for further question (skip if $model_id = 0):

```
 return Maintenance::whereHas('cars',function($query) use($model_id,$type) {
      if($model_id!=0){
          $query->where('model_id',$model_id);
      }
      $query->where('type',$type);
      })->get();
```

I did not tested it but it should work, otherwise let me know

Comment: That seem to work, thank you. Let say `model_id` is 0, how can I skip `$query->where('model_id',$model_id)` in the code?